# Easiest way to execute server side code via a HTML button click

Tags: php, html, button, webserver

Whats the easiest way to execute code on a webserver from a `HTML` button click? For example I would like a `Raspberry Pi` running `Apache` to present a webpage with buttons on it, each button should be able to be pressed which then executes a system command on the `Pi`. The `Pi` would be running locally so I am not concerned with security etc.

I know very little about web programming and have seen multiple suggestions, e.g. `PHP` with `HTML`, `jQuery` and `AJAX` but I just need a simple solution.

Comment: Use Ajax call on button press, that way you can run your server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxcall()">Button</a>
```

In your js (with jquery)

```
function ajaxcall() {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "myscript.php",  
        data: {
            var1  :val1
        },
        success: function(response){
            // do something
        }
    })
}
```

In your php

```
<?php
echo exec('your server command to exec');
?>
```

Comment: I tried this way but nothing is executed on the server. When I click the button the server should setup a TCP connection to another device but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: All that happens in an alert pops up saying "<?php
echo exec('netcat 192.168.0.5 40000');
?>" but netcat is never actually run

Comment: Working now, didn't have PHP installed...

Answer (score 1):

Learn AJAX, its very simple.

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){    // this ajax will call on button click whose id is "btn"
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',   // url of file                     
            type: 'POST',         // get or post                         
            data: {
                var1  :val1,     // variables list (key-value pair) 
                var2  :val2
            },
            success: function(response){    // response from process.php
                // do your stuff here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**P.S.** Don't forget to include the jquery library from CDN or from local

[Ajax Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I know little about web programming so this answer is too complex for me to use

Answer (score 0):

you can add ajax call on button click

```
$.ajax(function(){
      url : 'demo.php', //server  script (php) return json/html response
      method:'POST',
      data:'{key : value}' , //parameter you need tosend
     dataType:'json',// return type html/json
     success:function(res){
         console.log(res); //res contains result 
        //you can user result as you want
     },
     error:{
        //error message
    },

})
```